# OpenCV: Find all non-zero coordinates of a binary Mat image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, computer-science

I'm atttempting to find the non-zero (x,y) coordinates of a binary image.

I've found a few references to the function `countNonZero()` which only counts the non-zero coordinates and `findNonZero()` which I'm unsure how to access or use since it seems to have been removed from the documentation completely.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229951/opencv-locations-of-all-non-zero-pixels-in-binary-image) is the closest reference I found, but still not helpful at all. I would appreciate any specific help.

Edit:
- To specify, this is using C++

Comment: [`findNonZero()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190) description is within operations on array section currently.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/18551/opencv-java-how-to-access-coordinates-returned-by/) is an explanation for how `findNonZero()` saves non-zero elements. The following codes should be useful to access non-zero coordinates of your **binary** image. Method 1 used `findNonZero()` in OpenCV, and Method 2 checked every pixels to find the non-zero (positive) ones.

**Method 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Mat img = imread("binary image");
    Mat nonZeroCoordinates;
    findNonZero(img, nonZeroCoordinates);
    for (int i = 0; i < nonZeroCoordinates.total(); i++ ) {
        cout << "Zero#" << i << ": " << nonZeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i).x << ", " << nonZeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i).y << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Mat img = imread("binary image");
    for (int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++ ) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++) {
            if (img.at<uchar>(j, i) > 0) {  
                cout << i << ", " << j << endl;     // Do your operations
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying: 'findNonZero()' was not declared in this scope. What do I need to import to even be able to use this function?

Comment: Yes, I've successfully compiled and run everything from loading images, displaying windows to using Canny edge detection and thresholding.

Comment: Hope **Method 2** helps!

Comment: The answer to your problem is pretty simple, it needs at least OpenCV 2.4.4.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229951/opencv-locations-of-all-non-zero-pixels-in-binary-image/15235291#15235291

Comment: loop order should be reversed: iterate over rows, then columns. OpenCV's Mat container is stored in row-major order, so iterating over columns is cache unfriendly.

Answer (score 5):

There is the following source code that was [supplied for OpenCV 2.4.3](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2205), which may be helpful:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <vector>

/*! @brief find non-zero elements in a Matrix
 *
 * Given a binary matrix (likely returned from a comparison
 * operation such as compare(), >, ==, etc, return all of
 * the non-zero indices as a std::vector<cv::Point> (x,y)
 *
 * This function aims to replicate the functionality of
 * Matlab's command of the same name
 *
 * Example:
 * \code
 *  // find the edges in an image
 *  Mat edges, thresh;
 *  sobel(image, edges);
 *  // theshold the edges
 *  thresh = edges > 0.1;
 *  // find the non-zero components so we can do something useful with them later
 *  vector<Point> idx;
 *  find(thresh, idx);
 * \endcode
 *
 * @param binary the input image (type CV_8UC1)
 * @param idx the output vector of Points corresponding to non-zero indices in the input
 */
void find(const cv::Mat& binary, std::vector<cv::Point> &idx) {

    assert(binary.cols > 0 && binary.rows > 0 && binary.channels() == 1 && binary.depth() == CV_8U);
    const int M = binary.rows;
    const int N = binary.cols;
    for (int m = 0; m < M; ++m) {
        const char* bin_ptr = binary.ptr<char>(m);
        for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n) {
            if (bin_ptr[n] > 0) idx.push_back(cv::Point(n,m));
        }
    }
}
```

Note - it looks like the function signature was wrong so I've changed the output `vector` to pass-by-reference.

Comment: This function doesn't seem to help, my vector<Point coordinates; variable appears empty and won't even enter the loop. Here is my basic implementation. http://pastebin.com/Rznhb4wv

Comment: See above edit - it looks like the vector was being passed by value, so I've amended the code and added a note.

Comment: It still appears empty. I checked by using coordinates.size() and it equals 0. (variables explained in pastebin link above).

Comment: @Dmor574 Then perhaps you are not passing a single-channel greyscale image? The code above assumes CV_8UC1 and would need changing for anything else. If it's not that, then is it possible that your image really does have no zero pixels? The code is quite simple.

Comment: I believe that it might be possible that its in a different format, but @WangYudong, his second method worked (I'm unsure if its relevant).

Answer (score -3):

you can find it without using  findNonZero() this opencv method. rather u can get it by simply using 2 for loops. here is the snippet. hope it can help u.

**

```
for(int i = 0 ;i <image.rows() ; i++){// image : the binary image
            for(int j = 0; j< image.cols() ; j++){
                double[] returned = image.get(i,j); 
                int value = (int) returned[0]; 
                if(value==255){
                System.out.println("x: " +i + "\ty: "+j);// returned the (x,y) //co ordinates of all white pixels.
                }
            }

        }
```

**