# Opencv findNonZero returns array instead of matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to store the cordinates of the nonzero points in a binary image. I have found that this is posible using the funciton findNonzero from OpenCV but it returns the coordinates as a vector of size [numerofnonzeropoints] I guess that refering to the points as if the image was a vector of size DxD, instead of a 2d matrix where the coordinates are displayed as [x,y] way. Do you know if there is any way to do that? Maybe another function which could perform better?
Thanks!

Comment: May be [minmaxloc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxloc)

Comment: `I want to store the cordinates of the nonzero points in a binary image.` No, you don't. This statement makes no sense. A binary image does not store coordinates. Now, if you want to create a binary image in which each pixel is either white (1) for nonzero pixels in the original image or black (0) for zero pixels in the original image, that's entirely possible.

Comment: Sorry I dindn't make myself clear. I have binary image and I want to store the coordinates of the nonzero pixels in a 2Column matrix.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242662/opencv-find-all-non-zero-coordinates-of-a-binary-mat-image.