# Error in findnonzero() while storing the coordinates of non zero elements in vector<Point>

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mat

I was trying to store the non-zero elements indices of a Mat img1 into vector vp1 but it shows an `cv::Exception at memory location` error. This happens when the mat does not contain any non-zero element. Example code is below. where finding non-zero element indicies from img and storing in vp is successful but storing non-zero  elements indicies from img1 to vp1 shows error. Any help to solve this will be appreciated. I want the coordinates in Vector of point only because my rest of the algorithm is running based on it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main() {
    Mat img(10, 10, CV_8U, Scalar::all(0));
    img.at<uchar>(0,2)=1;
    vector<Point> vp;
    findNonZero(img, vp);

    Mat img1(10, 10, CV_8U, Scalar::all(0));
    vector<Point> vp1;
    findNonZero(img1, vp1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i get : `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (idx.isContinuous()) in cv::findNonZero, file ..\
..\..\modules\core\src\stat.cpp, line 3315`  - well, it checks for countNonZero() before, but does not bail out if none were found. bug, i'd say.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242662/opencv-find-all-non-zero-coordinates-of-a-binary-mat-image

Comment: @berak well then i can first check `countNonZero()` is not zero before   calling `findnonzero` would help i guess but it will add one extra complexity

Comment: @Velthune i have read that post already but what i need wasnt there

Comment: sAm, - you will have to, yes.

Comment: opencv3.0 has fixed this bug.

Answer (score 2):

This error is because of no non zero elements in the cv::Mat.
I think it is corrected in updated versions.

Though it increases the complexity, I give a simple solution (as @berak explained in comment)

```
vector<Point> locations;
int count = countNonZero(binaryMat);
if(count < 0)
{
    findNonZero(binaryMat,locations);
}
```