# Opencv obatin certain pixel RGB value based on mask

Tags: c++, opencv

My title may not be clear enough, but please look carefully on the following description.Thanks in advance.

I have a RGB image and a binary mask image:

```
Mat img = imread("test.jpg")
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8U);
```

Give some ones to the mask, assume the number of ones is N. Now the nonzero coordinates are known, based on these coordinates, we can surely obtain the corresponding pixel RGB value of the origin image.I know this can be accomplished by the following code:

```
Mat colors = Mat::zeros(N, 3, CV_8U);
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < mask.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < mask.cols; j++)
    {
        if (mask.at<uchar>(i, j) == 1)
        {
            colors.at<uchar>(counter, 0) = img.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
            colors.at<uchar>(counter, 1) = img.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
            colors.at<uchar>(counter, 2) = img.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2];
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

And the coords will be as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX7m3.png)

However, this two layer of for loop costs too much time. I was wondering if there is a faster method to obatin colors, hope you guys can understand what I was trying to convey.

PS:If I can use python, this can be done in only one sentence:

```
colors = img[mask == 1]
```

Comment: Why is the destination `Mat` called `coords`, when you're not storing coordinates in it, but rather pixel values from the input image? | Also, that Python code is incorrect, numpy arrays are not callable. Did you mean `img[mask==1]`? Furthermore, it doesn't produce a list of coordinates either.

Comment: Thank you for your kind remind:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are flexible with using any other open source library using C++, try `Armadillo`. You can do all linear algebra operations with it and also, you can reduce above code to one line(similar to your Python code snippet).

Or

Try `findNonZero()`function and find all coordinates in image containing non-zero values. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19244484/7514664

Comment: findNonZero(mask, nonzeroCoordinates);
int counter = 0;
for(int i=0; i<nonzeroCoordinates.total(); i++)
{
 coords.at<uchar>(counter, 0) = img.at<Vec3b>(nonzeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i).x, nonzeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i).y)[0];
 coords.at<uchar>(counter, 1) = img.at<Vec3b>(nonzeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i).x, nonzeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i).y)[1];
 coords.at<uchar>(counter, 2) = img.at<Vec3b>(nonzeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i).x, nonzeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i).y)[2];
 counter++;
}

Comment: Try to use Armadillo Library then. I have used Armadillo for such operations and it is comparatively fast as compared to OpenCV.

Comment: You can also try this method too in OpenCV: 1. Multiply image by mask. 2. Convert image matrix into vector. 3. sort values of vector in ascending order. 3. Reject all the zero value coordinates. 



I can try if you can provide image and mas

Comment: Thanks, I've searched about the Armadillo and find it a very powerful tool, but my project only allows me to use opencv.

Comment: you can define mask by yourself, here is the image:https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/02/06-train-cat-shake-hands.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The `.at()` method is the slowest way to access `Mat` values in C++. Fastest is to use pointers, but best practice is an iterator. See the OpenCV [tutorial on scanning images](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html).

Just a note, even though Python's syntax is nice for something like this, it still has to loop through all of the elements at the end of the day---and since it has some overhead before this, it's de-facto slower than C++ loops with pointers. You necessarily need to loop through all the elements regardless of your library, you're doing comparisons with the mask for every element.

Comment: Well I think I didn't make it clearly...What if the mask matrix is sparse? You will spend much time on traversing the matrix. Some exiting functions may have their modified algorithm to deal with this situation, which is what I'm trying to find.

Comment: Sparse matrices are stored differently, the non-zero elements are stored with their index so you can just index with them. If you want a sparse matrix for indexing, then create one and use it for indexing. General masks are not stored as sparse matrices, though. If you want to *create* a sparse matrix from your mask, then you'll have to loop over the mask all the same just to create it.

Comment: Suppose you have a sparse binary mask; that is, you just store indices corresponding to the non zero elements (note this is what you get with `findNonZero()` as the other answer mentions). Then you simply index the image at those points.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with optimization enabled, try profiling this version and tell us if it is faster:

```
vector<Vec3b> colors;
if (img.isContinuous() && mask.isContinuous()) {
    auto pimg = img.ptr<Vec3b>();
    for (auto pmask = mask.datastart; pmask < mask.dataend; ++pmask, ++pimg) {
        if (*pmask)
            colors.emplace_back(*pimg);
    }
}
else {
    for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; ++r) {
        auto prowimg = img.ptr<Vec3b>(r);
        auto prowmask = img.ptr(r);
        for (int c = 0; c < img.cols; ++c) {
            if (prowmask[c])
                colors.emplace_back(prowimg[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you know the size of colors, reserve the space for it beforehand.

Comment: I've tried your version, but when I use a for loop to look up colors, which is for(int i=0; i<colors.size(); i++)
  cout << colors[i] << endl;    I've got an incorrect result.

Comment: How did you check it? I've tried and it has the same results as your code. Here you can find a series of tests: https://ideone.com/1nJuBV