# OpenCV equivalent of np.where()

Tags: opencv, go, matrix, computer-vision

When using [gocv](https://godoc.org/gocv.io/x/gocv) package it is possible, for example, to perform [template matching](https://godoc.org/gocv.io/x/gocv#MatchTemplate) of a pattern within an image. The package also provide the [MinMaxLoc](https://godoc.org/gocv.io/x/gocv#MinMaxLoc) function to retrieve locations of minimums and maximums within the matrix.

However, in below python example, the writer uses [numpy.Where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to threshold the matrix and get locations of multiple maximums. The python [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function is used to glue values together so they are like a slice `[][2]int`, the inner slice being xs and ys of the matches found.

The syntax `loc[::-1]` [reverses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877008/4466350) the array.

The star operator in `zip(*loc..)` is being used to unpack the slices given to zip.

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_rgb = cv.imread('mario.png')
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv.imread('mario_coin.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
cv.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

How do I implement the same `np.where` algorithm in Go to get the multiple locations after the threshold is applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV has a built-in (semi-)equivalent function to `np.where()`, which is [`findNonZero()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190). As implied by the name, it finds the non-zero elements in an image, which is what `np.where()` does when called with a single argument, as [the numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) state.

And this is available in the golang bindings as well. From the [`gocv` docs on FindNonZero](https://godoc.org/gocv.io/x/gocv#FindNonZero):

> ```
> func FindNonZero(src Mat, idx *Mat)
> ```
>
> FindNonZero returns the list of locations of non-zero pixels.
>
> For further details, please see: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190

Note: `np.where()` returns indexes in array order, that is, (row, col) or (i, j) which is opposite to typical image indexing (x, y). That is why `loc` is reversed in Python. When using `findNonZero()` you won't need to do that, since OpenCV always uses (x, y) for points.

Comment: can you also explain the advantage of using numpy version over opencv version of this algorithm ? if any! i m not clear about to why the two exist...

Comment: @mh-cbon people can use either; you'll see numpy functions a lot because OpenCV uses numpy for matrix representation in Python instead of the native `cv::Mat` (there's a lot of good reasons for this), and that means you can just use numpy functions on images directly---and a lot of people know numpy better than OpenCV. There's no general reason to prefer it (one might be a little faster on certain platforms, you can test the timing if you like).

Comment: something is not clear about findNonZero output format. Using the c++ library it appears people do `nonZeroCoordinates.at<Point>(i).x `. But with gocv i don t find the equivalent Point method. Meanwhile, `findNonZero` returns a mat type `cv32sc2` with 9 rows, 1 col, 2 channels. I have not found how to turn those values into locations yet. I have read about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242662/opencv-find-all-non-zero-coordinates-of-a-binary-mat-image and understand the second method. But i would like o stick to method 1, and try to exploit findNonZero return matrix. Can you help again?

Comment: I mean, i m unclear about the format output of findNonZero, especially like how many various format can it return, and how to handle them all. I guess...

Comment: Also, if i were to take xs from channels 0 and ys from channel 1 because channel length == 2, i found a lot of similar values off by 1 pixel, how can i flatten this ? are those questions out of topic ?

Comment: @mh-cbon you are correct that each channel corresponds to each dimension of the data (channel 0 is x, channel 1 is y), this is a common output format for OpenCV. Can you please edit your original post with code showing the off by one issues? I can edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this I hope a full example keeps you from spending days hitting your head against the wall and reading the same google results over and over until something clicks.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "os"

    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func OpenImage(path string) (image.Image, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    img, _, err := image.Decode(f)
    return img, err
}

func main() {
    src := gocv.IMRead("haystack.png", gocv.IMReadGrayScale)
    tgt := gocv.IMRead("needle.png", gocv.IMReadGrayScale)
    if src.Empty() {
        fmt.Printf("failed to read image")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    if tgt.Empty() {
        fmt.Printf("failed to read image")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Get image size
    tgtImg, _ := tgt.ToImage()
    iX, iY := tgtImg.Bounds().Size().X, tgtImg.Bounds().Size().Y

    // Perform a match template operation
    res := gocv.NewMat()
    gocv.MatchTemplate(src, tgt, &res, gocv.TmSqdiffNormed, gocv.NewMat())

    // Set a thresh hold. Using the `gocv.TmSqdiffNormed` confidence levels are
    // reversed. Meaning the lowest value is actually the greatest confidence.
    // So here I perform an Inverse Binary Threshold setting all values
    // above 0.16 to 1.
    thresh := gocv.NewMat()
    gocv.Threshold(res, &thresh, 0.16, 1.0, gocv.ThresholdBinaryInv)

    // Filter out all the non-zero values.
    gocv.FindNonZero(thresh, &res)

    // FindNonZero returns a list or vector of locations in the form of a gocv.Mat when using gocv.
    // There may be a better way to do this, but I iterate through each found location getting the int vector in value
    // at each row. I have to convert the returned int32 values into ints. Then draw a rectangle around each point.
    //
    // The result of get res.GetVeciAt(i, 0) is just a slice of x, y integers so each value can be accessed by
    // using slice/array syntax.
    for i := 0; i < res.Rows(); i++ {
        x, y := res.GetVeciAt(i, 0)[0], res.GetVeciAt(i, 0)[1]
        xi, yi := int(x), int(y)
        gocv.Rectangle(&src, image.Rect(xi, yi, xi+iX, yi+iY), color.RGBA{0, 0, 0, 1}, 2)
    }

    w := gocv.NewWindow("Test")
    w.IMShow(src)
    if w.WaitKey(0) > 1 {
        os.Exit(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get all confidence levels of each x,y?