# c++ : "find non zero-elements of cv::mat" not working as intended

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, find, mat

I implemented a function which gives you the indices of all non-zero elements of a cv::mat format matrix. I want to identify the white area of this binary image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVJ7N.png .
 I want to receive the same result as from Matlab's "find" function.My code looks as follows (I hope the experts won't get a heart attack):

```
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\ml\ml.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
void findIndex(Mat imgmat, std::vector <std::vector <int> > &indices);

int main(void)
{
String img;
Mat imgmat;
img = "Mask120.png";
imgmat = imread(img);
std::vector <std::vector <int> > indices;
findIndex(imgmat, indices);
return 0;
}


void findIndex(Mat mask, std::vector< std::vector<int> >& indices){
int x_ind[100000]; // ugly, I know
int y_ind[100000];
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < mask.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mask.cols; j++) {
        if (mask.at<uchar>(i, j) == 255) {
            x_ind[k] = j;
            y_ind[k] = i;
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
}
indices.resize(2, std::vector<int>(k));

for (int m = 0; m < k; m++) {
    indices[0][m] = x_ind[m];
    indices[1][m] = y_ind[m];
}
}
```

It gives out two vectors as it should, but the results differ to those of Matlab's "find" and are obviously not correct. With find, there are in total around 22000 non-zero elements, this method identifies around 57000. Also, the first index which is marked as non-zero is at i = 119 and j = 561, corresponding to the point (562/120) of my binary image, which is not a white point.

Any ideas on where I have made a mistake is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you interested in a correction of your implementation or do you only want the result? In the latter case, this question is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15229951). OpenCV has a function `cv::findNonZero()` which does exactly that.

Comment: just saying , 1) you only check for x==255, not for x !=0   2) `imgmat = imread(img);` will load a 3channel bgr Mat, you need a grayscale, and a binarization pass before applying your function.

Comment: I used method 2 of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242662/opencv-find-all-non-zero-coordinates-of-a-binary-mat-image , because I want a 2 vector output instead of a Mat output. It seemed a easier for me to implement than method 1, if this cannot be corrected, I will give that a try as well of course!

Comment: thanks berak! that seems to solve it. applying imgmat = imread(img, 0) gives a more reasonable output at first sight.

Answer (score 1):

I can give a simple solution for your problem

where input cv::Mat is maskMat(it should be CV_8UC1)
The output will be updated in locations vector as Points of x and y co-ordinates

```
Mat whiteMat = maskMat == 255;
vector<Point> locations;
int count = countNonZero(binaryMat);
if(count < 0)
{
    findNonZero(binaryMat,locations);
}
```

Some higher version of opencv above 3.0

```
Mat whiteMat = maskMat == 255;
vector<Point> locations;
findNonZero(binaryMat,locations);
```